# Function Spaces

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

What is exactly the difference between $L^2$ space and ${\ell}^1$ space? I believe that one of them is the space of square of square integrable functions.

Does it have to do with one is for series and other for integration?

Thank You.

Comment: As far as I remember: small $\ell$: for sequences (wrt to summation). Big $L$: for functions (wrt to integration).
In your question, one of them is the space of square-integrable functions (wrt to some measure, implicitly the Lebesgue one); the second is the space of absolutely convergent series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$L^2(\Bbb R)$ is the space of square-integrable real functions:
$$L^2(\Bbb R) = \left\{ f: \Bbb R \longrightarrow \Bbb R  \mid \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|^2 \, dx < \infty \right\}.$$
Note that the above is not quite right; we say two functions $f, g \in L^2(\Bbb R)$ are equivalent if they take the same values outside of a set of measure zero.

$\ell^1(\Bbb R)$, on the other hand, is the space of absolutely convergent series:
$$\ell^1(\Bbb R) = \left\{ \{a_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty \mid \sum_{n = 1}^\infty |a_n| < \infty \right\}.$$

In general,
$$L^p(\Bbb R) = \left\{ f: \Bbb R \longrightarrow \Bbb R  \mid \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|^p \, dx < \infty \right\}$$
for $p \geq 1$ where we identify $f, g \in L^p(\Bbb R)$ if they agree outside of a set of measure zero, and
$$\ell^p(\Bbb R) = \left\{ \{a_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty \mid \sum_{n = 1}^\infty |a_n|^p < \infty \right\}.$$

If you learn measure theory at some point, you will see that there is a unifying definition of $L^p$ spaces that include the above examples as special cases: $L^p(\Bbb R)$ will be the $L^p$ space associated to $\Bbb R$ with the Lebesgue measure, and $\ell^p(\Bbb R)$ will be the $L^p$ space associated to $\Bbb N$ with the counting measure.